# Can I bring nicotine pouches from my home country into the US?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, legal, smoking

I am 20 and in my country I can legally buy nicotine pouches. In US however, I can not, because to purchase them you have to be over 21. My question is, does this law only apply to buying goods but not consuming (because I would already have them in my luggage, bought legally) or does it also prohibit being in possession of such items?

Comment: There's no _federal_ PUP (Possession and Use Penalties) legislation but there's a mishmash of state and municipal legislation, very unevenly enforced. The border guard is federal and certainly won't enforce any of them. But, AFAIK the import rules also have a 21 year old limit. But I can't find anything official about this, the only reference I can find is the duty free exemption for over 21 year old US residents which you are not and because of this I am just commenting.

Comment: In the US there's also a mishmash of Federal agencies with different enforcement priorities. You may run into someone from the DEA or ATF (where T stands for Tobacco) which may care much more about what's in your luggage in that regard than the average CBP customs officer.

Answer (score 3):

These are apparently in the form of small packets of white powder.  They will certainly attract attention from officialdom and they'll possibly want to test them in case they're an illegal substance.  Also note that too much (of anything) and you could be hit for importing for commercial purposes or evading taxes or duties.  This is the sort of thing I'd recommend not bring across a border as it's just inviting problems.